# For what $\alpha$ is $\int_{0}^{1}(x-\sin(x))^\alpha dx$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem is stated as the following:

> For what $\alpha$ is $\int_{0}^{1}(x-\sin(x))^\alpha dx$ convergent?

**Solution:**

---

Case I : $\boxed{\alpha \geq 0}$

---

Clearly, $(x-\sin(x))^\alpha$ is greter than $0$, since $x > \sin(x)$ in $[0,1]$

We can use the comparision theorem as following:

$0 \leq \int_{0}^{1}(x-\sin(x))^\alpha dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^\alpha dx $

The last inequality comes from the fact that $0 \leq \sin(x) \leq \sin(1)$ in our given interval, hence, we choose the smallest of the two to get a bigger integral.

$\int_{0}^{1}(x)^\alpha dx $ converges for $\forall \alpha \geq 0$.

---

Case II : $\boxed{\alpha < 0}$

---

Let $\beta = - \alpha$

$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(x-\sin(x))^\beta} dx \leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(x-1)^\beta} dx $

Which converges for $\beta > 1$, or in other words, for $\alpha < -1$. But what happens in the interval $(-1,0)$? I can't figure out what to do in this case. I'd be glad if you could share any ideas / tips. I also realized, using Desmos as a calculator, that in fact, it doesn't even converge for $\alpha < -1$, so what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it converges for $\beta > 1$, as it is opposite

Comment: Use $x-\sin x\sim\tfrac16x^3$.

Comment: @649: Edite your post. The integral does not converge for $\alpha\lt-1$

Comment: @J.G. I haven't seen that inequality before :/

Comment: @Tanamas Technically, it's an asymptotic relation, which is all we need here. (For small $x>0$, $x-\sin x\in\frac16x^3-\frac{1}{5!}x^5+O(x^7)$, so if you insisted on replacing $\sim$ with an inequality sign it would be $<$.)